# Date conversion to given format MYSQL

Tags: mysql, function, date

here i got a date format and a given date i need to convert the date into the format can anyone help me to do that.

```
 i have tried with couple of mysql functions like  date_format  etc..

  29-AUG-12 06.06.32.000000000 PM,DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM
```

Thanx in advance..

Comment: In which format date is coming and in which format you want to convert it?

Comment: i want to convert into timestamp format

Comment: which format you want to convert?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a solution like this according to format date is coming and in which format you want to convert

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('14 Aug 2014 07:46:17:000000', '%d %b %Y %T:%f'),'%d-%m-%Y    %h:%i %p') AS T

   output- 14-08-2014 07:46 AM
```